# insertion in a singly linked list at a specific position

Tags: c, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I was just going through singly linked list.. and I copied this piece of code from reference book.. but I don't know how to run it in main.. what should  I pass as an argument in struct node *new? I have no idea.. please help if possible....

```
struct node *insertatspecificposition(  struct node *new,int n){
    struct node *pred = head;
    if(n<=1){
        new->next = head;
        return new;
    }
    while(--n && pred != NULL ){
        pred = pred->next;
    }
    if(pred == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    new->next = pred->next;
    pred->next = new;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: 1) Copy/paste a *complete* example for a singly-linked list.  2) Step through the code under the debugger to understand how it works.  *DO NOT SKIP THIS*.  Walking through code in a debugger is arguably the single most powerful technique to understanding.  3) Once you understand "singly linked lists" in general, then (and *ONLY* then) turn your attention back to "insertatspecificposition()".  NOTE: we will *NOT* be able to help you without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Lakshit Chawla I advice to change the book to another book because this book is bad.:)

Comment: Have you tried reading the rest of the reference book, either before or after this specific code snippet?  I find it hard to believe that there isn't some other code to make a complete example from this very incomplete part.  Specifically, the definition of `struct node` and the global variable `head`, _at minimum_.  Finding the part that shows these would most likely lead you to an example of how they are being used.

Comment: well , thank you vlad for the code snippet.. your other demonstrative code is a bit complicated for me right now.. but I will definitely try it when I become a bit used to data structures.. for now , I am just a beginner..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presented function has a logical error.

When the position is set equal to `1` then the function inserts a new node before the current `head` node due to this code snippet

```
if(n<=1){
    new->next = head;
    return new;
}
```

So for example if you have an empty list (`head` is equal to `NULL`) then calling the function like

```
head = insertatspecificposition( a_new_node_with_value_1, 1 );
```

you will get the list that looks like

```
1 -> null
```

Now it is logical consistent that if for a next call of the function you will specify the position `2` you will get the list that looks like

```
1 -> 2 -> null
```

However such a call

```
head = insertatspecificposition( one_more_new_node_with_value_2, 2 );
```

returns `NULL` instead of returning the current value of the pointer `head`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *head;

struct node * create( int data )
{
    struct node *new = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    
    if ( new != NULL )
    {
        new->data = data;
        new->next = NULL;
    }
    
    return new;
}

struct node *insertatspecificposition(  struct node *new,int n){
    struct node *pred = head;
    if(n<=1){
        new->next = head;
        return new;
    }
    while(--n && pred != NULL ){
        pred = pred->next;
    }
    if(pred == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    new->next = pred->next;
    pred->next = new;
    return head;
}

void display( void )
{
    for ( struct node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    display();
    
    head = insertatspecificposition( create( 1 ), 1 );
    
    display();
    
    head = insertatspecificposition( create( 2 ), 2 );
    
    display();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
null
1 -> null
null
```

instead of the expected output

```
null
1 -> null
1 -> 2 -> null
```

Pay attention also to that the function should check whether the passed pointer `new` is not equal to `NULL`.

And it is not a good design when functions depend on a global variable.

As for me then I would write the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node * create( int data )
{
    struct node *new = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    
    if ( new != NULL )
    {
        new->data = data;
        new->next = NULL;
    }
    
    return new;
}

int insertatspecificposition(  struct node **head, int data, size_t n )
{
    struct node *new_node = create( data );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        while ( n-- && *head != NULL )
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
        
        new_node->next = *head;
        
        *head = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

FILE * display( const struct node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    
    putc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    insertatspecificposition( &head, 1, 0 );
    
    putc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    insertatspecificposition( &head, 3, 1 );
    
    putc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    insertatspecificposition( &head, 2, 1 );
    
    putc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    insertatspecificposition( &head, 4, 3 );
    
    putc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
null
1 -> null
1 -> 3 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
```

If the specified position is greater than or equal to the number of nodes in the list then the new node is appended to the tail of the list.

Positions as indices for arrays in C start from 0.

Of course you need at least one more function that will clear the list that is that will free all the allocated memory.

Comment: @4386427 There is nothing hard, The book is written by a low-qualified programmer and nothing more. At least the parameter that specifies the position shall be of an unsigned integer type. I suspect that the book is published in India.